# Remove Change data capture manually

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, change-data-capture

I'm having a serious problem with one of my production databases.

The database was enabled for change data capture which was performing quite well. Last month we had a server meltdown where several disks were affected and data was lost. We then recoverd the database backups from tapes and restored them on the freshly installed database server.

The problem which I'm facing now is as follows:

- the `sys.database` states that my database is not enabled for cdc
- the database contains the cdc schema, user, tables, sp & functions
- the `sys.sp_cdc_enable_db` throws an error stating the the schema & user 'cdc' are already existing so it can not create them and enabled the database for cdc
- the `sys.sp_cdc_disable_db` will not delete the cdc leftovers since it belives the the database is not enabled for cdc
- the cdc leftovers can not be deleted manualy since they are all system stored procedures & functions

So now I'm stuck with a database which can't be enabled for cdc since it already has all of the cdc components created, and cdc can't be disabled since it's not signaled in the sys.database that cdc is enabled.

Is there any solution for my issues, execpt creating a new database and migrating all of the object (except cdc) & data to the newley created database?

Comment: Did it get fixed? Any update you can share? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still looking for an answer to this old question - try the steps described on this page to remove CDC objects manually:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3003/manual-cleanup-change-data-capture-for-a-sql-server-database/